# Java - Double FOR with recursion

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, recursion

i'm having trouble with a method with a double for loop and recusion. I know what is happening there, becuz i can make it go away from the `j for` but when i try to get out of the `i for`  it just continue to `j for` and it's not what I wanted to do...

Code above:

```
void RemoverDuplicatas(int tamanho, boolean remover) {

        for (int i = tableKm.getRowCount() - 1; i >= 31; i--) {
            for (int j = tableKm.getRowCount() - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                if (!(i == j)) {
                    if (tableKm
                            .getValueAt(i, 9)
                            .toString()
                            .toUpperCase()
                            .equals(tableKm.getValueAt(j, 9).toString()
                                    .toUpperCase())
                            && tableKm.getValueAt(i, 10).toString().equals("")) {
                        modeloKm.removeRow(i);
                        if (tableKm.getRowCount() > 31) {
                            RemoverDuplicatas(tableKm.getRowCount(), remover);
                        } else {
                            j = -1;
                            remover = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (remover == false){
                i = -1;
            }
        }

    }
```

Note that the code enter in the `else` statement and skips `j for` (ok, that's right), then he goes to the `if` below to put value on `i = -1`  to exit the `i for`, but then, he keeps going pass the i for and goes to `j for` and so on.
I've tried to put a return, tried a break (with labeling and without) but with no sucess.

***EDIT***
Guys thanks for tips and adivces. All i needeed was just `re-write` and remove the recursion. After I checked at all, *I didn't really needed it*. Thanks for all feedback.

Below my solution if anyone instersted:

```
void removerDuplicatas() {

        label1: for (int i = modeloKm.getRowCount() - 1; i > 30; i--) {
            label2: for (int j = modeloKm.getRowCount() - 1; j >=0; j--) {
                System.out.println(modeloKm.getRowCount() + " tamanho");
                if (!(i == j)) {
                    if (modeloKm
                            .getValueAt(i, 9)
                            .toString()
                            .toUpperCase()
                            .equals(modeloKm.getValueAt(j, 9).toString()
                                    .toUpperCase())
                            && modeloKm.getValueAt(i, 10).toString().equals("")) {
                        modeloKm.removeRow(i);
                        j = -1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is your data, what is the expected output? PS: methods do NOT start with capital letters.

Comment: Have you tried a *debugger*?

Comment: You asking how to quit from recursion?

Comment: Have you heard of the break keyword?

Comment: @stealthjong thx for advice, im deleting line of a Jtable, and I pass (rows, true) to start this method.
@ElliottFrisch I'm using eclipse, debugging there I see that when he checks the `i for` he just sets values back from `remover` to `true` and `i = tableRowCount()`

Comment: @talex I'm asking how to exit the loop entirely, cuz it get stuck at the `i for`
@MarkW I tried a `break` statement to stop the loop on `i for` but didn't work, it still goes on and on and on   x.x

Comment: @luispuff you need one break per loop, ie if some condition, set a flag and break from the inner loop... if that flag is set break from the outer loop shortly after

Comment: BTW: use labeled for-loops and continue/break expressions instead of setting the index variables to -1! This will make your code more readable and understandable.

Comment: @luispuff try break with label. Also you have infinite recursion here if tableKm have more than 31 row and `tableKm.getValueAt(i, 9).toString().toUpperCase().equals(tableKm.getValueAt(j, 9).toString().toUpperCase())&& tableKm.getValueAt(i, 10).toString().equals("")` is true.  probably `modeloKm.removeRow(i)` should be replaced with `tableKm.removeRow(i)`

Comment: You should never change for indexes, if you really need to consider using while loop. In your recursion the first thing you should do, before the loop, is to check for an exit condition. The tamanho parameter does nothing, right? Your recursion is very strange, you should rewrite, not just fix

Comment: Thanks all for tips and advices.  @cocorossello I just did like u suggest, analised again and rewrote. Thanks. For now on, gotta check if I really need recursion or not. Thanks all.